# Ошибка IndexError: list index out of range при изменении размера сетки

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, tkinter

Пишу код приложения в котором будет отображаться сетка кнопок для рисования. Через настройки можно будет изменять размер сетки. А также при открытии файла и его прочтения сетка сама будет изменять через заданные параметры в файле.

Прикрепляю часть кода в которой происходит ошибка:

```
class DirCAD:

    ROW = 5
    COLUMN = 3
    FIRST_COLOR = 'white'
    SECOND_COLOR = 'navy'

    START_GRID = []
    NEW_GRID = []

    for a in range(ROW):
        temp = []
        for b in range(COLUMN):
            temp.append(0)
        START_GRID.append(temp)
    print(START_GRID)

    def __init__(self):
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(DirCAD.ROW):
            temp = []
            for j in range(DirCAD.COLUMN):
                btn = MyButton(DirCAD.grid_frame, bd=1, width=2, height=1, x=i, y=j)
                btn.config(command=lambda button=btn: self.click(button))
                temp.append(btn)
            self.buttons.append(temp)

    @staticmethod
    def grid_definition():
        for i in range(0, DirCAD.ROW):
            temp = []
            for j in range(0, DirCAD.COLUMN):
                temp.append(0)
                print(temp)
            DirCAD.NEW_GRID.append(temp)

    def settings(self):

        tk.Label(win_settings, text='Количество рядов:').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        row_entry = tk.Entry(win_settings)
        row_entry.insert(0, DirCAD.ROW)
        row_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        tk.Label(win_settings, text='Количество колонок:').grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        column_entry = tk.Entry(win_settings)
        column_entry.insert(0, DirCAD.COLUMN)
        column_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        change_settings = tk.Button(win_settings, text='Применить',
                                    command=lambda: self.change_settings(row_entry, column_entry, first_color,
                                                                         second_color))
        change_settings.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    def change_settings(self, row: tk.Entry, column: tk.Entry, first_color: tk.Entry, second_color: tk.Entry):
        try:
            int(row.get()), int(column.get())
        except ValueError:
            showerror('Ошибка!', 'Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
            return
        DirCAD.ROW = int(row.get())
        DirCAD.COLUMN = int(column.get())
        DirCAD.FIRST_COLOR = str(first_color.get())
        DirCAD.SECOND_COLOR = str(second_color.get())
        self.grid_definition()
        self.reload()

    def reload(self):
        [child.destroy() for child in self.grid_frame.winfo_children()]
        self.__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        for i in range(0, DirCAD.ROW):
            for j in range(0, DirCAD.COLUMN):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                if len(DirCAD.NEW_GRID) > 0:
                    if DirCAD.NEW_GRID[i][j] == 0:
                        btn.config(bg=DirCAD.FIRST_COLOR)
                    elif DirCAD.NEW_GRID[i][j] == 1:
                        btn.config(bg=DirCAD.SECOND_COLOR)
                else:
                    if DirCAD.START_GRID[i][j] == 0:
                        btn.config(bg=DirCAD.FIRST_COLOR)
                    elif DirCAD.START_GRID[i][j] == 1:
                        btn.config(bg=DirCAD.SECOND_COLOR)
                btn.grid(row=i, column=j)
```

Часть кода который работает и он ни как не связан с ошибкой я удалил.
Ошибка в терминале:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\alexb\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\diplom\main.py", line 114, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: self.change_settings(row_entry, column_entry, first_color,
  File "C:\Users\alexb\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\diplom\main.py", line 129, in change_settings
    self.reload()
  File "C:\Users\alexb\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\diplom\main.py", line 197, in reload
    self.create_widgets()
  File "C:\Users\alexb\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\diplom\main.py", line 216, in create_widgets
    if DirCAD.NEW_GRID[i][j] == 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Пишу на Python 3.9 с помощью библиотеки tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

*Перенесено из вопроса*

Проблема была решена изменение функции grid_defenition:

```
    def grid_definition():
        DirCAD.START_GRID = []
        for i in range(0, DirCAD.ROW):
            temp = []
            for j in range(0, DirCAD.COLUMN):
                temp.append(0)
                print(temp)
            DirCAD.START_GRID.append(temp)
```

Также везде удалил NEW_GRID как атрибут класса и оставил только для временного использования, то есть потом START_GRID приравнивается к NEW_GRID.